# Query Fields in Sharepoint db via Report Builder 

Tags: 2010, reporting-services, reports

Which is the best way to build a report to display the count of all upload files of a specific group of content types, foreach site collection? 
Should I use the table AllDocs to create de DataSet or is there an cleanest/direct way to go?

spregards